# How can I specify more space than the maximum of material-ui specified?

Tags: reactjs, gridview, material-ui

I have two elements in the grid. Codes are

```
<Grid container spacing={window.innerWidth > 960 ? 40: 0}>
    <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
        <MallsNearby />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
        <MallsEventsSlider />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

From its [documentation](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/#spacing), it has the max spacing of 40, but what if I want more spacing? How can I give more spacing than the 40?

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI uses the spacing prop to select and apply a precomputed style (`spacing-xs-<spacing value>`) to the container element, which you can override, see [here](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#css-api).

This style applies a margin of `-<spacing value> / 2` and a width of `calc(100% + <spacing value>px)` to the container element, and a padding of `<spacing value> / 2` to all children item elements of the container element, so you could alternatively override (or skip altogether) the default spacing and add your own manually with a custom class.